# Fixed background breaks overflow hidden of border radius on inner elements on Safari 7

Tags: safari, css-position, css

I want to position several elements inside a round `div` with a `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden`, in front of a `fixed` background :

```
<html><head>
<style>
    .background {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .rounded {
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        border-radius: 200px;
        -moz-border-radius: 200px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="background" style="background-color: black;">
</div>

<div class="rounded">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 0;">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 200px;">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px;">
</div>
</body></html>
```

Here is a the online example: http://jsfiddle.net/windycrazy/kvLSh/5/.

This works fine on Chrome(32), Firefox(26), Safari 6, but the `border-radius` is not taken into account for the non-statically positioned `img` elements on Safari 7 and Safari Mobile.

Removing the `fixed` background solves the issue but I really need it.

Is there a way to keep the `fixed` background, `relative` or `absolute` positions of the `img` and the `border-radius`?